# Building system-wide macOS text editing tools

Tags: xcode, macos, cocoa

So, these little popups you get when typing on macOS:

[image: spelling suggestion popup]

They're unique in that they allow users to trigger an action immediately, not from the menu bar or a contextual menu (e.g. right click) They're common among most OSs' in some form, this just happens to be Apple's design.

This popup is 
1. System wide, working in browsers, many text editors, etc. 
2. Always where your eyes are when typing, at the text cursor/most recent word typed.

As this window is always below the cursor, I figure there's space above to add other typing tools that work in a similar way.

For any typing tool like that it really has to be system-wide, not just in a particular app.

I'm struggling to find useful leads as to which APIs cover this, and whether it's even possible to access this area of the macOS system.

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! Please take the [tour](http://stackoverflow.com/tour), have a look around, and read through the [help center](http://stackoverflow.com/help), in particular [How do I ask a good question?](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) and [What topics can I ask about here?](http://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic). This question might be too broad for SO.

Comment: @TimothyTruckle thanks :) I have a minor edit that can more clearly communicate my question, it would be greatly appreciated if you could point to the least clear parts of my question, so I can find a better way of communicating it

Comment: @TimothyTruckle I've rewritten the question, please let me know if it's unclear or too broad, the core question is "which APIs in macOS handle this widget, and can I access them"

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You may be able to program such a feature as an input method, using [InputMethodKit](https://developer.apple.com/reference/inputmethodkit).  Input methods are most commonly used for Asian language input, where there are many more characters than keys on a keyboard.  However, the API is more general than that.

Insofar as the pop-up you're citing as an example is a spell-checker, you may be able to customize it by building a [custom spell server](https://developer.apple.com/library/content/documentation/Cocoa/Conceptual/SpellCheck/Tasks/CreatingSpellServer.html). I assume the user will have to select your spelling service explicitly, though, for each document.

Comment: InputMethodKit looks like the way to go, thanks :) and in this case I won't need a custom spell server, but that page had some useful points about integrating things like this on a system level. With regards to the UI, do you happen to know which API governs that type of stuff? It seems like a mundane-but-unique feature, as it 'interacts' with text in realtime, which is key to creating other tools like it.

Comment: I'm not sure what you're asking.

Comment: you've answered my question and given me enough for a good bit of research :) you can ignore my followup questions, I'll find out more and come back when I can properly formulate a new question.